# Tape Drive Directory Path on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, path, java-native-interface, scsi

I have developed an application in Linux which invokes a DDS tape drive. In Linux I use a path to call the tape drive which is /dev/st0

The application is written in Java and it uses JNI to call its native function

I am trying to run my application on Windows 8.1 but obviously I get an error:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Do you know how to fix this problem?

This is the Java piece of code which triggers the issue:

```
public TapeJNI(String pathName){
    fd = new FileDescriptor();

    System.out.print("Opening device...");
    System.out.flush();
    try {
        tapeOpen(pathName); //here it is
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    }
    System.out.println("done!");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one tape drive the device path will be "\\.\Tape0"

Answer (score 1):

This answer is all written from a Win32 perspective — if I read your question properly, the fact you’re using Java isn’t really relevant (since the tape access is occurring via JNI).

You’re going to have to talk to the tape drive somewhat differently on Windows.  First off, it isn’t going to have a device file at `/dev/st0`.  Most likely you'll want to enumerate the attached devices using `SetupDiGetClassDevs()` passing `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_TAPE` as the class GUID, followed by `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces()`, then you can get the device path using `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()`.  You can then open it using `CreateFile()`.

Also, none of the tape IOCTLs you’re used to from Linux will work on Windows.  Instead, most likely you’ll want to send SCSI commands to the tape device using `DeviceIoControl()` and `IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`.

Note also that Windows does have some tape related APIs, which might obviate the need for sending SCSI commands (depending on your requirements).  See e.g. `GetTapeParameters()`

Comment: Thank you, It has been a very explanatory answer